# NullPointerException : Overriding constructor calling method of Base class in Derived class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I've this code snippet:

```
class Base {
    public Base() {
        method();
    }

    void method() {
        System.out.println("In Base");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    private String bar;

    public Derived() {
        bar="bar";
    }

    public void method() {
        System.out.println(bar.length());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base base=new Derived();
        base.method();
    }
}
```

On executing the code I got an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Derived.method(Main.java:22)
    at Base.<init>(Main.java:5)
    at Derived.<init>(Main.java:17)
    at Derived.main(Main.java:27)
```

I'm unable to understand why there is `NullPointerException` and the `stackTrace` of the exception. Anyone could help me to understand?

You can check the code [here](http://ideone.com/hcaBG8).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`new Derived()` creates a `Derived` object, which implies calling its super class constructor first, which in turn calls `method` - but you have overriden `method` so it is the child version of that method which is called. In that method, you call `bar.length` which has not been initialised yet.

Conclusion: it is almost never a good idea to call an overridable method in a constructor.

Comment: thank you for your answer. One more thing about the `stackTrace`, is `Derived.<init>` means its calling the constructor? And why it is named `<init>`?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal yes, `Derived.<init>` is `Derived`'s constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have given is an ***antipattern***. We should never invoke a method handling fields from a `constructor` for a simple reason that it might create **unexpected results**.

From your code, your are trying to initialize a field called `bar` in the `Derived` constructor. Now when you say `Base b = new Derived()`, the call happens in following fashion

1. Base static initializer  -- If you have
2. Derived Static Initializer -- If you have
3. Base block initializer -- If you have
4. Base Constructor --> this is
   the place you are calling `method()`
5. Derived Block initializer -- If you have
6. Derived constructor -->
   this is the place where you are initializing bar

Now due to **run time polymorphism**, in to No. 4, when the `Derived`'s `method()` gets called, the `bar` is not yet initialized to the value `"bar"` (since initialization happens at No. 6) , the NPE occurs